# Im getting errors in the following SQL clause

Tags: java, jdbc

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement cannot be cast to java.beans.Statement
        at CollegeLibrary.NotRegistered.DBStatement(NotRegistered.java:114)
        at CollegeLibrary.NotRegistered.<init>(NotRegistered.java:85)
        at CollegeLibrary.NotRegistered.main(NotRegistered.java:91)
Java Result: 1
```

with and error on the within these section

```
 ResultSet SelectQuery(Statement st) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            rs = st.executeQuery("select * from APP.STUDENT");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NotRegistered.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return rs;
    }


    void InsertQuery(Statement st) {

        try {
            if(_txtFname.getText().length()>0 & _txtLname.getText().length()>0& _txtAddress.getText().length()>0&_txtPhone.getText().length()>0&_txtDob.getText().length()>0&_txtSTcode.getText().length()>0){

    st.executeQuery("insert into APP.STUDENT values ('"+_txtFname.getText()+"','"+_txtLname.getText()+"','"+_txtAddress.getText()+"','"+_txtPhone.getText()+"','"+_txtDob.getText()+"','"+_txtSTcode.getText()+"')");
            }else{
                System.out.println("please fill up the form");
            }
              } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NotRegistered.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
void  UpdateQuery(Statement st) {

        try {
            if(_txtFname.getText().length()>0 & _txtLname.getText().length()>0){
            st.executeUpdate("update APP.STUDENT SET USERNAME='"+_txtFname.getText()+
                    "', PASSWORD='"+_txtLname.getText()
                    +"' where USERNAME='"+_oldData+"'");
            }else{
                System.out.println("please fill up the form");
            }
              } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NotRegistered.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
void  DeleteQuery(Statement st) {

        try {
            if(_txtFname.getText().length()>0 & _txtLname.getText().length()>0& _txtAddress.getText().length()>0&_txtPhone.getText().length()>0&_txtDob.getText().length()>0&_txtSTcode.getText().length()>0){
                System.out.println(" ");
            st.executeUpdate("delete from APP.STUDENT where USERNAME='"+_oldData+"'");
            }else{
                System.out.println("please fill up the form");
            }
              } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NotRegistered.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement cannot be cast to java.beans.Statement

I think you have the wrong `import` statement in your code.

There are [java.sql.Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) (which you want here), and [java.beans.Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/Statement.html) (which is something completely different).

I most cases, you want to use [java.sql.PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead anyway, which steps around the name conflict, too. Don't put literal values directly in the SQL, use bind variables.

Comment: This is what happens when you let your IDE choose the import without looking to see which one it's choosing.

Comment: In real life, however, you would very soon find out that none of the methods you want to call on "Statement" are there. I wonder why he added the cast in the first place. Everywhere you get a Statement from will return a java.sql.Statement, and the methods he showed seem to import the correct one, too (they have an executeQuery that returns a ResultSet). I cannot recall ever having to do an explicit cast to Statement.

Comment: Thanks guys I have tried to import the java.sql.statement but still getting the same problem

Comment: @dnyondo: Did you re-compile? You must have a cast to java.beans.Statement on line 114 in NotRegistered.java. The error message is quite unambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

You should import

```
java.sql.statment not java.bean.statement
```